# What happens if a shareholder of a publicly listed company does not exercise his or her right to vote?

Tags: shares, shareholder-meeting

I was wondering what happens if a shareholder of a publicly listed company does not exercise his or her right to vote.

I would be tempted to answer "nothing" but I am sure you guys know better.

Clarification: I'm asking what the consequences are for the shareholder, not for his missed vote

Comment: Dupe https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/99494/what-happens-to-my-vote-if-i-dont-return-a-proxy-form . Nothing happens to you directly, although if a proposed action fails due to lack of votes, then you don't get any benefit -- or cost -- the proposal would have provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not included. All votes for and against are counted and the proposal action. Non voters are not counted.

Few decisions by company due to regulations or individual policy need a minimum number of valid votes. Often the number of shares held by individuals is too small for it to matter.

Edit: There is no obligation to vote. No penalty or fines for individual share holders.